# Add vectors/matrices to a list of vectors/matrices

Tags: r, list, vector, append

I have a list of vectors or matrices, like below:

```
l <- list(1:3, 4:6)
l
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6
```

Now I want to add a new vector/matrix to the list. Using `c()` is not a good approach, since each item of the new vector will be added as single list elements:

```
c(l, 7:9)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6

# [[3]]
# [1] 7

# [[4]]
# [1] 8

# [[5]]
# [1] 9
```

Also `list()` does not work fine, it creates a nested list of length 2, rather a list of length 3:

```
list(l, 7:9)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6

# [[2]]
# [1] 7 8 9
```

What's the standard solution to this?

Comment: `c(l,list(7:9))` maybe. I think this might have been covered here previously though.

Comment: Thanks. I guessed it might be covered, I searched but I could not find a relevant question, at least with a clear topic. Hence I posted this simple question here.

Comment: to your credit I can't seem to find a duplicate question. If I don't find one soon I'll promote my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
do.call(c, list(l, list(7:9)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6

# [[3]]
# [1] 7 8 9
```

And if it were a matrix:

```
do.call(c, list(l, list(matrix(7:9))))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6

# [[3]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    7
# [2,]    8
# [3,]    9
```

If you want to add more than one vector or matrix, you can put them all in the second list:

```
do.call(c,list(l, list(matrix(7:9), 6:10)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6

# [[3]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    7
# [2,]    8
# [3,]    9

# [[4]]
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we replace `do.call()` with simply `c(l, list(7:9))` as @thelatemail has proposed above?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that later: `c(l, list(7:9))` should work